# Image doesn't display RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am having trouble displaying an image in a Shiny app.  The code is saved in Desktop, where I also have a www folder with logo.png.  I've set the working directory to the desktop, as well:

```
library(shiny)
library(png)

ui <- fluidPage(
  img(src="logo.png", height = 400, width = 400)
) #close fluidpage


server <- function(input, output, session){

} # closer server

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Here's how the output looks.
[image]

I prefer to have server and ui in the same file for ease of understanding.  Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: Does it display if you open it in browser?

Comment: This is odd. I've tried splitting server.R & ui.R, and [the documentation/guides](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson2/) say this is how it's done...

Comment: Not sure why this is the case, but it seems like it works if you are in a different working directory `(getwd() != <directory of your app.R>)` and then execute `runApp("appdir")` from your console. Slightly more information on single-file Shiny Apps can be found [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/single-file.html) although this particular issue with images isn't addressed

Comment: That hack works, but it breaks an excel sheet import I have using a fileInput widget and the readXL library.

Answer (score 6):

Similar Shiny `img` problem [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546344/8677693). Rather than executing the code directly or in console, creating a properly formatted `app.R` and clicking `Run App` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display your image. You can give a handson with HTML on Rshiny. Below is the modified code, which you can try. Hope it works

```
library(shiny)
library(png)

ui <- fluidPage(
 headerPanel(
  list(tags$head(tags$style()), 
     HTML('<img src="logo.png", height="400px"    
          style="float:right"/>','<p style="color:black"></p>')
         )#headerPanel closes
        ) #close fluidpage


       server <- function(input, output, session){

       } # closer server

       shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```