# Image not showing in Shiny app R

Tags: r, image, shiny

I have an image i'd like to embed into my shiny app, and have read as much as I can find on how to do it. Although, all I get is a blue question mark when I run my code.

This is the line of code I have added, within the `fluidPage` `ui` command

```
img(src="logo.png", align = "right",height='100px',width='400px')
```

My image has been placed in the project directory folder, as well as trying in a separate folder inside named www (as per [suggestion given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app))

EDIT: Code used in the following context:

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Test title"),

                img(src="logo.png", align = "right",height='100px',width='400px'),

                hr())
```

Comment: I've just checked that adding the code above to e.g. `sidebarPanel` inside `sidebarLayout` in `fluidPage` and placing the image in `www/logo.png` works just fine. Can you maybe share the code of the particular app which fails for you? Thanks!

Comment: I added the line of code inside fluidPage, after titlePanel. I have added a more comprehensive example in the OP.

Comment: This seems to work for me, see `runGitHub("aoles/SO_38011285")`. Maybe you have a typo in the image path, or some other problem with the image file itself?

Comment: Possibly. Its a mystery to me since yours works fine, yet mine will not show. The image path should be fine since the directory is set as the R project folder where the .app file is kept. Strange!

Comment: I have same issue. No rendering when using `img()` on the ui side. Using identical path but rendering from the server side works fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After coming back to this problem, I found that the solution is to simply format the Shiny code properly, by naming the R file `app.R`, and clicking `Run App` as opposed to selecting all of the code and running within the console.

Not sure how or why this makes a difference, but the numerous Shiny applications I have worked on since have all been resolved when doing this.

Comment: WOW. just wow. I have spent the whole morning troubleshooting this trivial error. Checking multiple times the image address, the www folder, the app name, the code and what not. I even placed the image at various places to see if that works.
AND THEN THIS ANSWER. I would not have guessed this in 100 or 1000 tries. I believe this should be reported at R Shiny Github repo. 

May all the lost people find there way here quicker than I did.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :). This problem caused me a huge headache so glad it helped you

Comment: Thank you so much @sym246 . You saved me so much agony

Comment: @sym246, very important issue you clarified. Has anyone opened an issue on github about that?

Comment: I hadn’t opened one, no. Not sure if anyone else has.

Comment: This problem costed a few hours of my time as well. Another thing you shouldn't do is to (out)source the ui/server code to another file in another folder.

Answer (score 5):

Just a note that may be helpful to someone else, it just happened to me: please double check if your `app.R` is in the root directory. I.e, `app.R` is on the same level as the `www` folder. I know it seems trivial, but if you (as I just did) put `app.R` into a subfolder and click `Run App`, the app can still run, just without the pictures.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. To solve this, just create a folder named 'www' in the same folder as your app.R script and put the images within that folder.

I found the solution to this problem in the tutorial video in this page: [Shiny Tutorial Video - Adding Static Content](https://vimeo.com/rstudioinc/review/131218530/212d8a5a7a/#t=1h36m54s)
Watch from 1h45min00sec.

Comment: This didn’t work (as per the suggestion in the OP). There seems to be a glitch when selecting the code and running it this way, as opposed to clicking ‘Run App’

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the name of your R code file is called “app.R" instead of called xxx.R. this error also happened to me