# R shiny - image does not appear

Tags: r, image, shiny

I am trying to insert a logo on my shiny page.

Here is a reproducible example:

app.R file:

`setwd(".../shinyApp")
source("ui.R")
source("server.R")
shinyApp(ui, server)`

I use the runApp button to run the app

ui.R file:

`ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Blabla"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId="min",
                  label="Values",
                  min = 10, max = 100, value = 10,sep=" "),
                  h6("Done by:"),
                  img(src='logo.png',height=50,width=50)
      ),
    mainPanel(
      h1("Main title"),
      p("First paragraph"),
      h2("Subtitle"),
      p("Second paragraph"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )))`

But this does not work ... I have a question mark error instead of my logo as if R could not find my image. The question mark is rightly located in my sidebarPanel though (and the text "Done by" appears).

I have put my image in a www directory since I have read in many places that it was a solution (here for ex: [Image not showing in Shiny app R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011285/image-not-showing-in-shiny-app-r)).

My shiny app structure is the following :

- an app.R file:
- a shinyApp directory containing : my ui.R, my server.R and the www directory which contains my logo.png

I have no idea what I have done wrong ... can anyone please help ? Many thanks !

Comment: please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have no idea how one can insert a slider on top of an image. Is the slider showing something?

Comment: Yes, please see my edits. The slider shows everything good except the image which does not appear... I have also tried to put the image outside the slider and it still does not work so I don't think this is the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to build your shiny application.

1. Defining ui and server in a single file and name it as `app.R`

   ```
   library(shiny)
   ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
     titlePanel("Blabla"),
     sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput(inputId="min",
                     label="Values",
                     min = 10, max = 100, value = 10,sep=" "),
         h6("Done by:"),
         img(src='logo.png',height=50,width=50)
       )

     )))

   server <- function(input, output, session) {
     } shinyApp(ui, server)
   ```
2. Defining ui and server as seperate pages and saving them as `ui.R` and `server.R`

Sample `ui.R` page

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Blabla"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId="min",
                  label="Values",
                  min = 10, max = 100, value = 10,sep=" "),
      h6("Done by:"),
      img(src='logo.png',height=50,width=50)
    )

  )))
```

Sample `server.R` page

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

}
```

Output of shiny

[image]

Comment: oh I see, and then if you define two separate ui and server files, how do you run the app ? you run them successively ?

Comment: If ui.R and server.R pages are in open, you could see an option `Run App`. Just click that option and shiny will run.

Comment: ok thank you very much, your solution indeed solved my problem ! I have put all my code in a single app.R file !! Thanks again !!