# Logo appears as a question mark on shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to add a logo on the top right corner of my shiny dashboard, however it appears a question mark. I have tried changing the height and width of the logo but it does not work. When you click on the logo it takes you to a website which does work but unable to see the logo on dashboard.

I have referenced to all these following articles but none of it could resolve my issue

[Adding a company Logo to ShinyDashboard header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440564/adding-a-company-logo-to-shinydashboard-header)

[Image not showing in Shiny app R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011285/image-not-showing-in-shiny-app-r)

[R shiny - image does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554837/r-shiny-image-does-not-appear)

This is the code I have written so far my dashboard header

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)
server <- function(input, output) {}


#Dashboard header carrying the title of the dashboard
header <- dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard"
                          ,tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                                   tags$a(href="https://www.mbm.net.nz/", 
                                          tags$img(height = "20px", src="Ascibe_logo.jpg", width = "200px")
                                   )),

                          dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                                       messageItem(
                                         from = "Sales Dept",
                                         message = "Sales are steady this month."),
                                       messageItem(
                                         from = "New User",
                                         message = "How do I register?",
                                         icon = icon("question"),
                                         time = "13:45"),
                                       messageItem(
                                         from = "Support",
                                         message = "The new server is ready.",
                                         icon = icon("life-ring"),
                                         time = "2014-12-01")),
                          dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                                       notificationItem(
                                         text = "5 new users today",
                                         icon("users")),
                                       notificationItem(
                                         text = "12 items delivered",
                                         icon("truck"),
                                         status = "success"),
                                       notificationItem(
                                         text = "Server load at 86%",
                                         icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                                         status = "warning"
                                       )),
                          dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "success",
                                       taskItem(value = 90, color = "green",
                                                "Documentation"
                                       ),
                                       taskItem(value = 17, color = "aqua",
                                                "Project X"
                                       ),
                                       taskItem(value = 75, color = "yellow",
                                                "Server deployment"
                                       ),
                                       taskItem(value = 80, color = "red",
                                                "Overall project")))
```

Can anyone please help me to get this issue resolved.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Have you placed your image with in a folder named `www` in the working directory? If not, create a folder with `www` name and paste all your images in that folder.

Comment: @msr_003 the suggestion helped. I placed them in www folder as suggested and it worked. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this help:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
app <- shinyApp(
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                              /* navbar (rest of the header) */
                              .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                              background-image:url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/4f32f57f8754b8e18aef1e01/50716878e4b03adec665056f/5081fc0084ae02360227cc7a/1445030506945/your-logo-here-27.png?format=300w");
                              background-position-x: 99%;
                              background-size: 80px 50px;
                              background-repeat: no-repeat;
                              background-color:#000;
                              }'
)))
    )
    ), 
server <- function(input, output) {}
)
runApp(app)
```