# Is there a way to display a .gif file in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I simply want to render a .gif file in an R shiny app. Is there a simple way to do this? I was unable to find a solution in the documentation.

Comment: Check out the "pre-rendered" section of https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html

Comment: Maybe check this out as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011285/image-not-showing-in-shiny-app-r/46546344#46546344

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  img(src="sample.gif", align = "left",height='250px',width='500px')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Make sure that the app.R has a folder called www where the gif is saved.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much. It was an issue with my file structure.